# response follow no entra al siguiente metodo

Tags: python, scraping, scrapy

estoy intentando pasar unas url al siguiente método usando response.follow de scrapy pero simplemente no llega a llamar al segundo metodo, es como si se cortara la ejecucion pero no estoy recibiendo ningun mensaje de error.

```
import scrapy
import re


class SpiderArtworkCategories(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'artwork_categories'
    art_urls = []
    page_number = 1
    start_urls = [
        'http://pstrial-2019-12-16.toscrape.com/browse/summertime'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'artwork_cagegories.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'
        }
    

    def parser_test(self, response, **kwargs):
        url = kwargs.get('url')
        print('###########################')
        print('INSIDE THIRD')
        print('###########################')
        yield {
            'hello': 'HOLA', 
            'url': url
        }

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        art_category = kwargs.get('art_category')
        art_link = kwargs.get('art_category')
        if art_category:
            art_category.extend(response.xpath('//div[@id="subcats"]//h3/../@href').getall())
        else:
            art_category = response.xpath('//div[@id="subcats"]//h3/../@href').getall()
        
        if len(response.xpath('//div[@id="subcats"]//h3/../@href').getall()) >= 1:
            for category in art_category:
                yield response.follow(category, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={'art_category': art_category, 'art_link': response.request.url})
        else:
            for link in art_link:
                next_link = 'http://pstrial-2019-12-16.toscrape.com{}'.format(link)
                print('###########################')
                print('NEXT LINK {}'.format(next_link))
                print('###########################')
                yield response.follow(next_link, callback=self.parser_test, cb_kwargs={'url':next_link})
```

Al ejecutarlo debería imprimir lo contenido en parser_test, pero no lo hace, es como si no llegara al método.